# Erro Nova ChartJs SQL Generator when using PostgreSQL

Tags: laravel, postgresql, chart.js, laravel-nova

**Describe the bug**

I'm trying to generate a chart, however when I pass the parameter "filter" to SQL Builder, more specifically the file "TotalRecordsController" assembles the query as if I were using MySQL, instead of mounting it for PostgreSQL.

Laravel: 8.40
PHP: 7.4
PostgreSQL: 12
Nova: 3.30
ChartJS: 0.3.5

- Linux Mint
- Chrome

My Code:

```
public function cards(Request $request)
    {
        $process_statuses= [
            ["label"=>"INITIAL" ,"color" => "#007BFF"],
            ['label'=>'CONVERTED' ,'color' => '#28A645'],
            ['label'=>'ERROR' ,'color' => '#DC3544'],
            ['label'=>'WAITING_TO_ERICH' ,'color' => '#17A2B8'],
            ['label'=>'WAITING_TO_CONVERT','color' => '#17A2B8']
        ];
        $series = [];
        foreach ($process_statuses as $status){

            $new_serie = [
                'label' => $status['label'],
                'filter'=>[
                    'key'=>'process_status',
                    'value'=>$status['label']
                ],
                'barPercentage' => 0.5,
                'backgroundColor' => $status['color'],
            ];

            $series = [...$series,$new_serie];
        }
        return [
 (new BarChart())
                ->title('Today Status')
                //->model(\App\Models\GoogleOfflineConversion::class)
                ->model('\App\Models\FacebookOfflineConversion')
                ->series($series)
                ->options([                    
                    'btnRefresh'=>true,
                    'uom' => 'hour',
                ])->width('full'),
        ];
    }
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'INITIAL'"
LINE 1: ... process_status = 'INITIAL' then 1 else 0 end) as 'INITIAL',...
                                                             ^ (SQL: select HOUR(facebook_offline_conversions.created_at) AS cat, HOUR(facebook_offline_conversions.created_at) AS catorder, sum(1) counted, SUM(CASE WHEN process_status = 'INITIAL' then 1 else 0 end) as 'INITIAL', SUM(CASE WHEN process_status = 'CONVERTED' then 1 else 0 end) as 'CONVERTED', SUM(CASE WHEN process_status = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) as 'ERROR', SUM(CASE WHEN process_status = 'WAITING_TO_ERICH' then 1 else 0 end) as 'WAITING_TO_ERICH', SUM(CASE WHEN process_status = 'WAITING_TO_CONVERT' then 1 else 0 end) as 'WAITING_TO_CONVERT' from "facebook_offline_conversions" where facebook_offline_conversions.created_at >= 2021-10-28 00:00:00 group by "catorder", "cat" order by "catorder" asc)
```

Migration of the my database:

```
Schema::create('facebook_offline_conversions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            $table->foreignUuid('company_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('refer_site_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreignUuid('site_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreignUuid('facebook_ads_site_credential_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('crm_order_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('fbc')->nullable();
            $table->longText('document_number')->nullable();
            $table->longText('email')->nullable();
            $table->longText('phone_number')->nullable();
            $table->float('value')->nullable();
            $table->string('currency')->nullable();
            $table->longText('city')->nullable();
            $table->longText('state')->nullable();
            $table->longText('zip_code')->nullable();
            $table->longText('country')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('conversion_time')->nullable();
            $table->longText('ip_address')->nullable();
            $table->longText('browser')->nullable();
            $table->string('process_status')->nullable();
            $table->integer('tries')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('approximated')->default(false);
            $table->json('conversion_response')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm resolving this problem. The solution is to change the file "src/api/TotalRecordsController" inside the folder "~/vendor/coroowicaksono/chart-js-integration" so that it suits PostgreSQL.